# Add signature to features

Tags: 7, features

I love to work with features! I often work with several colleges on the same feature and I'ld like to add a signature to the features. So we can see who worked last on the feature (without having to dig in Bitbucket).

It must be possible since the example Features do so:

[image]

But all I get are Unavailable signatures :(

[image]

Any one know this magic?

Comment: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/features/tree/theme/theme.inc << this would be a good place to start looking. sign seems to be passed through $vars during the form build process

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a patch which will allow users to enter an "Author" name when creating/updating a feature.
When provided, the signature will take the Authors value, if not fallback on standard workflow.

Setting the signature was my goal and I succeeded.  For those interested, here is the patch:

```
diff --git a/sites/all/modules/contrib/features/features.admin.inc b/sites/all/modules/contrib/features/features.admin.inc
index a4203a0..3c5c913 100644
--- a/sites/all/modules/contrib/features/features.admin.inc
+++ b/sites/all/modules/contrib/features/features.admin.inc
@@ -168,6 +168,15 @@ function features_export_form($form, $form_state, $feature = NULL) {
     '#size' => 30,
     '#element_validate' => array('features_export_form_validate_field'),
   );
+  $form['info']['author'] = array(
+    '#title' => t('Author'),
+    '#description' => t('Examples: Patrick, John'),
+    '#type' => 'textfield',
+    '#required' => FALSE,
+    '#default_value' => !empty($feature->info['author']) ? $feature->info['author'] : '',
+    '#size' => 30,
+    '#element_validate' => array('features_export_form_validate_field'),
+  );
   $form['advanced'] = array(
     '#type' => 'fieldset',
     '#title' => t('Advanced Options'),
@@ -832,7 +841,7 @@ function _features_export_generate($export, $form_state, $feature = NULL) {

   $module_name = $form_state['values']['module_name'];
   // Directly copy the following attributes from form_state
-  $attr = array('name', 'description', 'package', 'project path');
+  $attr = array('name', 'description', 'package', 'project path', 'author');
   foreach ($attr as $key) {
     $export[$key] = isset($form_state['values'][$key]) ? $form_state['values'][$key] : NULL;
   }
@@ -1083,7 +1092,10 @@ function features_admin_form($form, $form_state) {
       '#disabled' => $disabled,
     );

-    if (!empty($module->info['project status url'])) {
+    if (!empty($module->info['author'])) {
+      $uri = check_plain($module->info['author']);
+    }
+    else if (!empty($module->info['project status url'])) {
       $uri = l(truncate_utf8($module->info['project status url'], 35, TRUE, TRUE), $module->info['project status url']);
     }
     else if (isset($module->info['project'], $module->info['version'], $module->info['datestamp'])) {
```